# Phonegap: Barcode scanner doesn't work

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to implement in an application .I want to create a bar code scanner, but it  doesn't work.. My JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#barScan").click(function(){
       cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
     function (result) {
         alert("We got a barcode\n" +
               "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
               "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
               "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
     }, 
     function (error) {
         alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
     }
);
    });

});
 </script>
```